# Can Categories be used to hack a Multisite-like setup w/ a single MySql db?

Tags: categories, multisite, mysql

I have a project which will effectively create multiple blogs that will be fed existing content (don't worry, this isn't copyrighted content from other blogs or anything like that).  From a DB management and moderator point of view, and to limit hosting costs, I would like to avoid the built in multisite functionality which requires a separate DB for each blog.

I am wondering whether, with some intelligent duct-tape hacking, it is feasible to run multiple blogs in one WordPress blog that appears as many separate blogs.  I think that Categories might be hijacked to make this work.  Basically each separate "blog" is a separate category.

Is there anyone who has done this or has another, single DB multi blog approach (using WordPress)?  Words of wisdom or caution about the kind of tweak I am suggesting?

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstood,  Wordpress multisite works with only one database for all sites!

Comment: Really?  Perhaps this was true for older WordPress versions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 1 database for for multiple blogs.  WordPress Multisite does this for you by appending and additional prefix to the tables.

For example in an MS database with wp_ set as the prefix in wp-config.php the additional tables will have wp_1_, wp_2_, and so on.

Without using Multisite you can do this yourself by changing the prefix for each blog in the respective wp-config.php file.